# dependency management in c project

Tags: c, eclipse, svn

let me describe the situation first and then I will aks my question.

I have a very generic module A. It consist of one c and one h file. The only dependency it has is to stdint.h file.

There is also module B using module A (#include "module_A.h"). 
There is another module C also using module A. 
Both B and C modules has dependency to module A "managed" via svn:externals property to make sure anyone using module B or C has also module A checked out.

Modules B and C are pretty unrelated to each other. 
During the development of some project it happened that both modules B and C were needed. 
Svn:externals properties have been set in the project to get those modules into project directories. 
And now we have in project directory structure something like that:

```
src/module_B/module_B.c
src/module_B/module_B.h
src/module_B/module_A/module_A.c
src/module_B/module_A/module_A.h

src/module_C/module_C.c
src/module_C/module_C.h
src/module_C/module_A/module_A.c
src/module_C/module_A/module_A.h
```

The compiler detects duplicated definitions of functions and stops compilation with errors.

We use Eclipse to develop.

Question 1. How to solve such problem?

Question 2. If we dig deeper into this topic we might imagine a situation that module A has several revision and module B and C are pointing to different revisions of module A. How to solve  such problem?

Comment: Pehaps you need to guard your Header files using `#ifndef #define #endif`

Comment: @Dayalrai That won't help if module A has functions with external linkage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1:**

Your linker will go mad, if there is multiple definitions of the same function.
You need to make sure you only have 1 version of A in the project:

```
src/module_A/module_A.c
src/module_A/module_A.h

src/module_B/module_B.c
src/module_B/module_B.h

src/module_C/module_C.c
src/module_C/module_C.h
```

**Q2:**

Only way to make this work is to upgrade B and C to be compatible with the same version of the A.

Your header file for A should probably have version number information, which would indicate version compability:

```
// Version 1.2    
#define MODULE_A_VER_MAJOR 1 /* For backwards incompatible changes */
#define MODULE_A_VER_MINOR 2 /* For bug fixes */
```

Then you could add compile time checks to modules B and C to make sure those are not accidentally compiled with the wrong version of A.

```
#include "module_A.h"
// Require at least 1.1
#if MODULE_A_VER_MAJOR != 1 || MODULE_A_VER_MINOR < 1
    #error Invalid A version!
#endif
```

Comment: Of course I meant linker errors not compiler - sorry for that. But yes, I have come up to the same ideas as user694733. There needs to be a common repo and all modules have to be always compatible with latest changes in any modules dependent.

Answer (score 0):

> The compiler detects duplicated definitions of functions and stops compilation with errors.

Such errors always appear because of programming mistakes. Use header guards and never allocate any objects in a H file.

> If we dig deeper into this topic we might imagine a situation that module A has several revision and module B and C are pointing to different revisions of module A. How to solve such problem?

The scenario doesn't make any sense. There are two cases:

- If they both depend on A and only exist in the same project, then you will have to update B and C each time A is updated.
- Otherwise, if they exist in several projects, then for this discussion to make any sense, there must be a "global" repository which isn't project-specific, where you store the most recent version of every file. I.e your collection of files to be re-used in several projects. In this repo all files should be up to date.

  Lets say that you update A and C, but for some reason not B. That can only mean that B is project-specific - otherwise you *must* update it together with A. If it is project-specific, then it doesn't belong in the "global" repo, but rather in a project-specific one. And that sorts everything out, since in your project-specific repo, you can keep an old version of A around.